# angularjs how to grouping same set of variables

Tags: angularjs

I am having function in my controller.

```
$scope.TestFn = {
            func1: function() {
                console.log('in function TestFn func1')             
                },
            func2: function() {
                console.log('in function TestFn func2')             
                }   
        }
```

That i am calling in my directive as below,

```
<div ng-init="TestFn.func1()"><div>
```

This is working fine. What i want to know, what do we call this kind of functions arrangements. Like we are grouping relevant functions all together. And is it possible to have same way for declaring variables. For example,

```
$scope.Test.variable1 = 'value1';
$scope.Test.variable2 = 'value2';
```

Which i can use like `{{Test.variable1}}` or `{{Test.variable2}}`
It is essential for me to know because i am having many html template and want to keep all relevant functions and variables all together for easier management.

Thanks

Comment: do your templates have different controllers? You might want a _controllerAs_ syntax: `ng-controller="TestCtrl as Test"`, and then call scoped variables with `{{Test.variable1}}`

Comment: All templates are in same controller.

Comment: I think you up-voted my answer. If you think it clarifies things for you, perhaps you'd consider marking it as *the* correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you have doubts about this, but if you read [the Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) you'll see that both assigning variables and functions to `$scope` is just about the most basic standard thing you'd be expected to do do with a Scope object.

```
angular.module('scopeExample', [])
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.username = 'World';

    $scope.sayHello = function() {
        $scope.greeting = 'Hello ' + $scope.username + '!';
    };
}]);
```

> In the above example notice that the `MyController` assigns 'World' to the `username` property of the scope.

...

> Similarly the controller can assign behavior to scope as seen by the `sayHello` method, which is invoked when the user clicks on the 'greet' button.

So yes, you can assign variables as well as functions. It's what the scope is there for.

And no, there's no specific name for referring to functions in a map -which is what you're basically doing in your code sample. The `$scope` object can hold variables and functions structured in maps and arrays -or combinations of both.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. It gave me a lead to store all the variables in array form.